# ArrayList of ArrayList of ints in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I am working on writing a sudoku solver and I want the grid to be stored as an arraylist of arraylist of ints...each spot will have an arraylist of ints of all possible numbers (or the definite value).

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<int>> sudoku_board = new ArrayList <ArrayList<int>>();
```

Java is throwing me an error saying "dimensions expected after token" on the ints.

Comment: Why ArrayList? Just use normal `int[][]`

Comment: Also note if using Java 7 you can simply type set the right hand side of the expression to "new ArrayList<>();"  and it will infer its generic type from the left hand side.

Answer (score 10):

Generic type parameters require reference types, rather than primitive types. Use

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> sudoku_board = new ArrayList <ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Also when coding to an interface use the interface as the reference type, in this case `List`. Everything that appears within the generics should remain as the implementation type due to the [non co-variance of generics](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html).

From @assylias comment, a more generic type of list is

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

This will allow for `List` implementations types other than `ArrayList` to be added should refactoring be necessary later.

Comment: Why not `List<List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>> ();`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Integer` wrapper class instead `primitive`.

ArrayList wont allow `primitive` as type `argument`.

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> list= new ArrayList <ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Comment: i can uderstand continue.no problem

Comment: This doesn't just apply to ArrayList - no collection can contain primitives

Comment: @MarkChorley Yup.That's a Generic statement.But in this context Arraylist :)

Answer (score 2):

Arraylist is used to store objects not primitives, so change the signature accordingly.